# Recursive meny reading with non duplication

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I am trying to make a function that reads a many (page_id,page_title) from db, which i made recursive. Function is supposed to make indented nested UL-s like a tree for all existing pages, and is doing so as it should. Problem starts when i try to eliminate duplication from the recursive loop. For some reason in_array is NOT working as it should, or i am missing something. i work on PHP5.5.1.2.
Anyone knows what the problem here is?
My code as is now:

```
function nav($page_set,$pages,$count){
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($page = mysqli_fetch_array($page_set)) {
        if(!in_array($page['page_id'],$pages)){
                echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page['page_id']) . "\">{$page["page_title"]}</a></li>";
                if (!is_null(get_pages($page['page_id'])))
                {
                $pages[$count]=$page['page_id'];
                $count++;
                nav(get_pages($page['page_id']),$pages,$count); 
                }   
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} 

function get_pages($page_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT page.page_id, page.page_parent, page.page_meny_position, page_lang_content.page_title FROM page JOIN page_lang_content ON page.page_id=page_lang_content.page_id ";
    if (isset($page_id))
    {
    $query .= " WHERE page.page_parent = ".$page_id;
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY `page`.`page_id` ASC ";
    $page_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    confirm_query($page_set);
    return $page_set;
}
```

AND function call:

```
<?php echo nav(get_pages(NULL),$pages=array(),$count=0)?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working as it should"? Though I think there's a typo in your code, here: `"\">{$page["page_title"]}</a></li>"` don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: It's displaying the tree as it should:  
Title1
    test7
    test8
        test12
        test13
            test14
            test15
            test16
    test9

Title2

test3

test4

    test10
    test11

test5

test6

test7

test8

    test12
    test13
        test14
        test15
        test16

test9

test10

test11

test12

test13

    test14
    test15
    test16

test14

test15

test16

test17,   but its still duplicating like:in_array($page['page_id'],$pages)) always returns FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Didn't test this, but I would assume that you get duplicates still because you are not actually storing all the page_ids in your $pages variable so that all the processed page_ids would be available on all of the recursion rounds. You need to return the $pages array in the recursion to make sure that it contains all the processed values (I also removed the count value as it didn't seem to have any meaning):

```
function nav($page_set,$pages)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($page = mysqli_fetch_array($page_set)) 
    {
        if(!in_array($page['page_id'],$pages))
        {
            echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page['page_id']) . "\">{$page["page_title"]}</a></li>";
            if (!is_null(get_pages($page['page_id'])))
            {
                $pages[]=$page['page_id'];
                $pages = nav(get_pages($page['page_id']),$pages); 
            }   
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    return $pages;
}
```

and similarly the function call modified

```
<?php echo nav(get_pages(NULL),$pages=array())?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, just edited the call to be:<?php nav(get_pages(NULL),$pages=array())?>, otherwise returned Array to string conversion